# jQuery scrolling, active menu highlighting

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I have some problem with my jQuery scrolling script. I have succeed with creating a fixed menu at the top of my one-page site. The menu items is scrolling to the right area in the page with jquery, and the active menu item is highlighted.

The problem is that I want to highlight the menu item when the user scrolls manually too. I thaught that the script below would fix this, but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
if($('#contact').offset() < $(document).scrollTop()) { // #contact is the element who one of the menu items scroll to.

    $('.link-contact').css({ // The menu item
        'background' : 'url(wp-content/themes/theme/images/menu.bg.png)',
        'color' : '#999'

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be that your if statement is only firing once when the page loads.
Have you tried putting it inside a scroll event?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($('#contact').offset().top < $(document).scrollTop()) {
        ...
    }
});
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> .offset() returns an object containing the properties top and left.

In your case `$('#contact').offset()` returns an object so your if statement will always be false.

That said, access the top property value like this: `$('#contact').offset().top`